# webpack minification with angularjs 1.X doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am facing some issue in using webpack minification with angularjs 1.x I have successfully generated the webpack bundle and it works fine. The moment I use minification , my application stops working. I am using front-end-maven plugin to integrate webpack with maven. I am also using the $inject to inject dependencies in my angularjs code.

**pom.xml**

```
 <execution>
            <id>webpack build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>webpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- -p is for minification -->
                <arguments>-p</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
```

**Angularjs code**

```
'use strict';
AsyncService .$inject = ['$http'];
var  AsyncService =  function($http) {
}

module.exports = AsyncService;
```

**This is what I see in generated bundle**

```
{"use strict";
n.$inject=["$http"];
var n=function(t)
{ 
}
```

$http got converted to t. I think this is wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: May be your problem is that you first use variable and then create it? (AsyncService)

Comment: yes that too. Main issue was I missed this ling in config file.              plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})]